# Create a named map in CartoDB

Tags: carto, curl

I'm trying to create a template map following [this tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#named-maps-1) from the cartoDB's maps API.

My template.json file

```
{
  version: "0.0.1",
  name: "template_1",
  // embedded authorization certificate 
  auth: {
   method: "open" 
  },
  placeholders: {
      color: {
        type:"css_color",
        default:"blue"
      },
      del_s: {
        type:"sql_literal",
        default: "19420210"
      },
      del_n: {
        type:"number",
        default: 19420210
      }
  },
  layergroup: {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "layers": [{
      "type": "cartodb",
      "options": {
        "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
        "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: <%= color %>; }",
        "sql": "select * from table1 WHERE del = <%= del_s %>",
        "interactivity": ["cartodb_id","del","gk"]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "cartodb",
      "options": {
        "cartocss_version": "2.1.1", 
        "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: red; }",
        "sql": "SELECT * from table2 WHERE del = <%= del_n %>",
        "interactivity": [ "cartodb_id","del"] 
      }
    }]
  } 
}
```

When I try to make the request to create the template..

```
curl -X POST \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d @template.json \
   'https://docs.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named?api_key=568kaka8bc89'
```

I can not connect, I get an error:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to docs.cartodb.com:443; Connection timed out
```

anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

Try with my username, and get an "internal server error"

```
curl -X POST \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d @template.json \
   'https://myusername.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named?api_key=myapikey'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to create the template, think it's a bug either the documentation or behaviour. It seems that you need to use quotation marks around the fields and can't use comments in the code

like this:

```
{ "version": "0.0.1", "name": "template_io", "auth": {"method": "open" }..
```

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in the documentation, we are fixing, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

in the curl you need to use your username instead of docs, like

```
curl -X POST \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d @template.json \
   'https://USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

We use docs as a placeholder, so replace USERNAME and YOUR_API_KEY with your cartodb username and api key

Comment: thanks Javi, I have already tried, with my username it give me an 'internal server error'

Comment: when I try the curl -X GET 'http://username.cartodb.com/tiles/template?api_key=mykey' the response is: {"template_ids":["username@tpl_9342e510_31db_11e4_9581_0e7333fa50","username@tpl_a9d222b0_3054_11e4_a4ec_230854a1cb","username@tpl_b188bba_31fd_11e4_8c9a_0edb5057"]}

Comment: when I use the -X GET command listed above, I got a list of the visualizations I made in the cartodb UI, I am not able to create a template map with a post resquest: got 'internal server error'